# C# Property Encapsulation

Tags: c#, properties, coding-style

C# properties are one of the most expressive tools I've found in a c family language. My question is why can't the "backing" field be within the property block? What reasoning is this not allowed?

```
public int Salary //Compile error
{
    int salary = 1000;
    get {} //custom use of salary
    set {} 
}
```

I find it rather clunky to do the following

```
int salary = 1000; //poor encapsulation but working code

public int Salary
{
    get {} //edit the private field salary
    set {} 
}
```

I've done some optimization of some code by memozing properties using the following pattern

```
int field;
bool flag = false;
public int Field 
{
    get
    {
        if (flag)
            return field;
        flag = true;
        return field = expensiveOperation();
    }
}
```

I would really like to move these variables in the scope of the property since they have no reason to be in the scope of the instance

```
public int Field //compile error
{
    int field;
    bool flag = false;
    get
    {
        if (flag)
            return field;
        flag = true;
        return field = expensiveOperation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why private field should be inside the property block. Property is encapsulating a private field. That field should be available inside your class, irrespective of the property.

Comment: I find that most of the time my fields are only used within the property setter or getter. I don't see the point of them cluttering the instance space when they could be just as effective in the property block.

Comment: Agree with @TommyDDD seems more natural to keep things arranged locally together, but what happens when a field instance needs to be shared over multiple properties? Your suggestion should be optional though or?

Comment: Yes I think it should be optional not enforced. Specifically my flag example is how I keep latency down when accessing a data base or ensuring I only do an expensive operation once. Using linq its not uncommon for my code to request a field multiple times. bool flag is irrelevant from the class scope other than notifying the instance that the work has already been computed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have property, which work with its own data, not related to object where property sits, then I think you should extract that property from your class. Intent of properties is to work with data which are related to class where property is declared, and have scope of whole class.

Also keep in mind - property is just a syntax sugar for pair of methods.

---

Side note: you can use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for lazy initialization of field. E.g.

```
Lazy<int> field = new Lazy<int>(() => expensiveOperation());
```

Comment: Your data classes dont contain any logic? If not consider using fields instead of properties.

Comment: @TommyDDD each cell (property) belongs to row (class instance). Thus cell data should have scope of class.

Comment: @Sergey thanks for the Lazy tip. I'll look into this and it looks like a good solution for my pattern. ACCEPTED ANSWER

Answer (score 1):

I think having a field declaration inside the property scope would only make sense if that scope defined the life cycle of the field. But it doesn't. The field belongs to the class and exists as long as the instance of the class exists (for instance fields).

As for your lazy initialization pattern, take a look at Lazy class. It nicely encapsulates expensive initialization and also provides thread-safety.

Comment: Thats an insightful note on field life span. It would be ambiguous I suppose.